# JSF Primefaces Tree Node Beginner

Tags: primefaces

I tried using the example of showcase tuts from primefaces.org. I copied exactly the same text in my xhtml file as well as TreeBean.java

But The tree structure never appears in the browser(m using IE9). An empty block appears instead of the tree. Is there anything I need to keep in mind when using tree nodes?

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>PrimeFaces</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Header
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                <h:form id="form">
                    <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" id="tree">
                        <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
                            <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="lblNode"/>
                        </p:treeNode>
                    </p:tree>
                </h:form> 
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                Welcome to PrimeFaces
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>

</f:view>
```

Comment: Can you add code from your bean?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and copy a TreeBean class too. It is avaible for every example on primefaces showcase site, next to xhtml's source code. To make it visible for EL you have to additionally annotate it @Named or @ManagedBean, and give it some reasonable lifecycle scope.

//EDIT:

```
@Named
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class TreeBean {  ... }
```

Comment: I have included the same class from the example.